# How do I override the styles from JQuery UI tabs?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, overriding, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using JQuery 1.12 with JQuery UI (1.12).  I want to override the padding that is inserted in each tab, but only on certain small mobile browsers, so I defined this in my CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
        margin: 0px;  
    }
    .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-anchor {
        padding: .5em .5em; 
    }
}
```

However, when I load up my page on Mac Chrome's mobile browser emulator (basically Mac Chrome), although I see my styles included in teh insepctor, the default classes are taking precedence over my classes ...

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-anchor {
float: left;
padding: .5em 1em;
text-decoration: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px)
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-anchor {
    padding: .5em .5em;
}
```

I can't figure out how to copy it properly into SO, but there's a strike through line over "padding: .5em .5em;" in the media section, indicating it has been overridden.  How do I make my UI tab CSS definition take precedence?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity and as a last resort, you can always add `!important` to your rules to force specificity.

Comment: I may be confusing my terminology, but by "specificity" do you mean that the thing with "specificity" is respected over the thing that does not?

Comment: specificity refers to the strength of a CSS selector. Like for `<p class="whatever" id="foo">`, `#foo` has higher specificity than `.whatever`. So if you define both `#foo` and `.whatever`, `#foo` will have precedence, regardless where it's defined, because it has higher specificity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `!imporant` is [highly discouraged](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/). Proper way to step up specificity in this case would be along the lines of:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .ui-tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav {
        margin: 0px;  
    }
    .ui-tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav a.ui-tabs-anchor {
        padding: .5em .5em; 
    }
}
```

I am heightening the specificity with `ul` and `a` selectors. Others have linked to official documentation but I want to reiterate that there are countless ways to do this. I could have just as easily done something generic such as adding an `html` or `body` selector to the beginning of every rule.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    body .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
        margin: 0px;  
    }
    body .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-anchor {
        padding: .5em .5em; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.  SO is not letting me award the bounty for another day so I'll come back then.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
   .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
     margin: 0px !important;  
   }
   .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-anchor {
     padding: .5em .5em !important; 
   }
}
```

http://www.standardista.com/css3/css-specificity/ explains specificity in more detail, but the above code will work because the !important declaration will out-specify the standard styles.

Answer (score 0):

Using `!important` is very ugly and bad idea!
Try sth like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .ui-tabs.ui-tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav {
        margin: 0px;  
    }
    .ui-tabs.ui-tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav a.ui-tabs-anchor {
        padding: .5em .5em; 
    }
}
```

This will increase your priority of css syntax.